# problemas al ejecutar dos eventos change en una funcion

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Resulta que estoy tratando que unos select me carguen en funcion de otros, con el primer select logro que suceda, pero cuando quiero cargar otro select no me funciona.

Este codigo es el que estoy usando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#curso').change(function(){
  $.post("./actions/estudiantes.php", {curso:$('#curso').val()}, function(data){
    $('#estudiante').html(data);
   });
 });
 
 $('#materia').change(function(){
  $.post("./actions/actividades.php", {materia:$('#materia').val()}, function(data){
    $('#actividad').html(data);
   });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="curso">Curso</label>
                     <select name="curso" size="1" id="curso" class="select">
                            <option value="0">Seleccionar curso</option>
                            <?php 
                                   $datos = conseguirCursos($db);
                                   if(!empty($datos)):
                                          while($dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)):
                                   ?>
                                                 <option value="<?=$dato['codigo_curso']?>">
                                                        <?=$dato['descripcion']?>
                                                 </option>
                                   <?php
                                          endwhile;
                                   endif;
                            ?>
                     </select>
                     
                     <label for="estudiante" id="notas">Estudiante</label>
                     <select name="estudiante" size="1" id="estudiante" class="selet">
                     </select>
                     
                     <label for="materia" id="materia">Materia</label>
                     <select name="materia" size="1" id="materia" class="selet">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione una materia</option>
                     <?php 
                            $datos = conseguirMaterias($db);
                            if(!empty($datos)):
                                   while($dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)):
     ?> 
                                          <option value="<?=$dato['cdigo_materia']?>">
                                                 <?=trim($dato['nombre'])?>
                                          </option>
     <?php
                                   endwhile;
                            endif;
                     ?>
                     </select>
                     
                     
                     <label for="actividad" id="notas">Actividad</label>
                     <select name="actividad" size="1" id="actividad" class="selet">
                     </select>
```

Cuando escojo un curso me carga los estudiantes, pero cuando escogo una materia no me carga las actividades que estan asociadas a esa materia.

agradeceria mucho su ayuda, con este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica en consola que estás pasando el valor de materia:

```
$('#materia').change(function(){
        console.log($('#materia').val());
});
```

Si te muestra el valor de la materia, revisa actividades.php, para ello en el navegador accede a este archivo directamente y verifica que si al pasarle el valor materia te trae resultados. Por ejemplo:

http://localhost/tusistema/actions/actividades.php?materia=algunvalorexistente

Como en el javascript lo estás pasando por post, para pruebas en el navegador directamente, cambia $_POST por $_GET

Comment: Gtacias @GreidaMJ encontre el error el id lo tenia repetido